# Change Play Store (web) device order

Tags: google-play-store

My device order in [Play Store web](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en) is currently like so:

[image]

I haven't even powered on the Nexus 4 in a month. How do I make Note 4 the default without disabling Nexus 4 altogether in [Play Store Settings](https://play.google.com/settings?hl=en)?

Answer (score 0):

The list is sorted by last used date.

Go to the Play Store on your phone, maybe download or update an app, and the last used date should be set to the current date. And next time, it should be at the top.

Comment: Not true. I still shows my previous phone—which I have not used for more then 3 months now—as the default

Answer (score -1):

As far I know, it can't be done. Google Play lists the devices in alphabetical order by default.

Comment: Isn't it possible to rename the device instead? Looking from the screenshot, I doubt Google named "Galaxy Note" as "Galay Note" instead.

Comment: That "nickname" can be changed by pressing "Edit" in the [Store Settings](https://play.google.com/settings?hl=en) (which didn't change anything), but now, for some magical reason, the Note 4 is actually back in the default position, and is showing *"Last used: March 30, 2015"*. I guess it's just sorted by the usage date, and then by name?

Comment: @AndrewT. Samsung, not Google. Nice catch ;).